# Why can't I use C# 4 default parameters in Mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, c#-4.0

Mono works fine with my app, but when I try to compile a function like

```
int Yo(int a, int b = 1) {
     // blah...
}
```

It doesn't work, it says that "Default parameter specifiers are not permitted"

According to Mono's website

> The Mono C# compiler is considered feature complete for C# 1.0, C# 2.0 and C# 3.0 (ECMA). A preview of C# 4.0 is distributed with Mono 2.6, and a complete C# 4.0 implementation is available with Mono 2.8 or when building Mono from our trunk source code release.

How can I successfully compile it?

Comment: Um, what version of Mono are you running?  This seems like a pretty important detail to add to your post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our C# 4.0 compiler is available as the "dmcs" command as opposed to the "gmcs", "smcs" or "mcs" commands.

After Mono 2.8 we will work towards having a single command line compiler that will let you select the various profiles using a flag, but for now we created different scripts that act as frontends to the API profile/language level that you want to use

Comment: Wow didn't expect Miguel to answer my question :) Thank you. I really like Mono, and I wish you good luck. You are really making .NET cross platform.

P.S. How can I ask MonoDevelop to use dmcs to compile my ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: If you have a 4.0 runtime installed, you should be able to select target framework version in Project Options.

Comment: Hm... I don't have this option though I have .NET 4 installed.

Here's the screenshot:

http://s51.radikal.ru/i134/1008/c5/2c9d0994e7af.jpg

Comment: That looks like a limitation in MonoDevelop's UI.   Make sure you have the "dmcs" command available.

Comment: You know, I installed Ubuntu and MonoDevelop 2.4... And it worked! The weird thing is that I still had Runtime Version: Mono/.NET 3.5 but worked! Here's the screenshot

http://s52.radikal.ru/i137/1008/c9/906f62ac5bde.jpg

 the page displays "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC on Mono!2" (which is correct) but the IDE marked it as a syntax error. (???)

Now I'll have to completely switch to Ubuntu :)  (I wish you supported it officially, but badgerports also works)

Comment: For those who met exactly the same problem. I tried mono 2.8 and monodevelop 2.4.2 on windows and it still requires that switching to .net 4.0, which is not an option for me now.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have gotten Mono 2.8... It has not been released yet, so you will need to download the sources. The git archive page is [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-2-8).

It is not ready yet, so you will need to get it from source and compile mono yourself before you can use C# 4.0 features and this is only provided that the mono team has in fact finished writing these features into their compiler.

Comment: Oh that's what I thought the problem was. Will it work fine with ASP.NET MVC 2 framework?

Comment: @Alex - The current mono should work with MVC 2 as is. The 2.8 branch is not ready yet - I wouldn't risk using it for a production app.